# Can I have a link within a WP UI Spoiler

Tags: plugins, links

I'm using the WP UI plugin, and have a page set up with spoiler shortcodes so that you can "click to show" and "click to hide". Here's a link to the page in question:
http://goinspire.com/faq/

My problem is this: I want to include a hyperlink within the text of one of the spoilers (which you only see after you "click to show"). When I inserted the html at wordpress "Edit Page", it displayed the actual html, instead of showing as a link.

Here's my spoiler:
`[wpspoiler name="Do I need to buy travel insurance?" style="ui-lightness"]GoInspire highly recommends buying travel insurance for non-refundable tickets and land costs.
Speak to our agent at 845-425-8255 ext. 209 for more info, or click <a href="https://www.mhross.com/index.php/consumer/index/goin0028" target="_blank">here</a> to read about our plans.[/wpspoiler]`

Is there a way past this?

Comment: don't see any problem on the given url..

Comment: Can you look under this spoiler: Do I need to buy travel insurance?

Comment: are you putting the code on visual editor? make sure you put it in text editor.

Comment: I'm putting it in the text editor

Comment: You should be able to add a link in the spoiler with WP UI.  Please edit your post, click on the "text" or "HTML" tab, and copy the code for the spoiler with the link that is giving you trouble. Include the `[wpspoiler]` and `[/wpspoiler]` tags and everything in between.  Then edit your question here and paste that code so we can see it.

Comment: will do that now

Comment: I was able to make your spoiler code work on my site.  The < > and " characters in your code are encoded on your site, breaking the link.  Try this: Delete that spoiler code from your site and click the Update button to save your post.  Then copy the text from your question here and paste it back in to your post (in the "text" editor).  Update your post, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make your spoiler code work on my site.  The `<`, `>`, and `"` characters in your spoiler code are encoded on your site, breaking the link.  I think that either your theme or one of your plugins is encoding those characters.

To test your theme, temporarily switch to one of the default themes (such as Twenty Twelve) and see if that fixes the problem.

If not, deactivate your plugins and see if that fixes the problem.  If it does, reactivate your plugins, one at a time, until the problem comes back.

Comment: I've got plenty of other links on my site, though!

Comment: Is there any way to find the problem besides for testing out different themes? It's a live site, and I don't have a dev version set up to test with.

Comment: It only takes a few minutes to switch your theme, load your page to test, then switch back.  If you are worried about your site looking strange for a few minutes, then do it in the middle of the night to minimize the traffic on your site at the time of the test.  Alternatively, set up a dev site and try to reproduce the problem there.

Comment: Is it easy to set up a dev site?

Comment: Setting up a WordPress site for development purposes is just as easy as setting up a WordPress site for production purposes.

Comment: I wasn't the one who set up our site. I think I'll try switching the theme quickly.

Comment: Okay, I tried switching the theme, and the page still loads wrong, showing the html of the link.

Comment: I just deactivated all of my plugins, one at a time, and checked the page after one. Every time, the page still shows the html.

Comment: Do you have any more ideas for me??

Comment: I still think that one of your plugins or your theme is causing the problem, but when you deactivated them and tested your page, the damage was already done in the post.  I would switch your theme to Twenty Twelve, deactivate all plugins except for WP UI, and then create a new page or post with the [wpspoiler] shortcode in it, and see if that behaves correctly.